# "MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume" with EKS and EFS

Tags: amazon-eks, amazon-efs

I'm trying to set up EFS with EKS, but when I deploy my pod, I get errors like `MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "efs-pv3" : rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded`
in my events.

What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the security groups assigned to the EFS mount points. I had created the mount points, but the security groups did not allow traffic from the VPC holding my EKS nodes.

Once I added a properly configured security group to the EFS mount points, that error disappeared.

Comment: I had a similar issue. Fixed it by including all the subnet in my EKS VPC while creating an efs mount target. 
At first, I was only including one subnet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an automated way to use [Phyxx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62887740/7270039).

At first, I was using the **private** subnets of my cluster, this led to the error mentioned by this thread. After seeing the answered mentioned, I noticed all my nodes were in the **public** subnet. Therefore I only had to switch "Private" to "Public" to make it work.

Here is script that worked for me :

```sh
CLUSTER_REGION=<YOUR_CLUSTER_REGION>
CLUSTER_NAME=<YOUR_CLUSTER_NAME>
EFS_SECURITY_GROUP_NAME=<YOUR_EFS_SECURITY_GROUP_NAME>
EFS_FILE_SYSTEM_NAME<YOUR_EFS_FILE_SYSTEM_NAME>

create_efs_mount_targets() {
    file_system_id=$(aws efs describe-file-systems \
                            --region $CLUSTER_REGION \
                            --query "FileSystems[?Name=='$EFS_FILE_SYSTEM_NAME'].FileSystemId" \
                            --output text) \
    && security_group_id=$(aws ec2 describe-security-groups \
    --region $CLUSTER_REGION \
    --query 'SecurityGroups[*]' \
    --output json \
    | jq -r 'map(select(.GroupName=="'$EFS_SECURITY_GROUP_NAME'")) | .[].GroupId') \
    && public_cluster_subnets=$(aws ec2 describe-subnets \
                --region $CLUSTER_REGION \
                --output json \
                --filters Name=tag:alpha.eksctl.io/cluster-name,Values=$CLUSTER_NAME Name=tag:aws:cloudformation:logical-id,Values=SubnetPublic* \
                | jq -r '.Subnets[].SubnetId')
    if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
        exit 1
    fi
    for subnet in ${public_cluster_subnets[@]}
    do
        echo "Attempting to create mount target in "$subnet"..."

        aws efs create-mount-target \
            --file-system-id $file_system_id \
            --subnet-id $subnet \
            --security-groups $security_group_id \
        &> /dev/null \
        && echo "Mount target created!"
    done
}

create_efs_mount_targets
```

Comment: I also facing like issue....can you tell me...has there any way to work with efs using private subnet when i create my EKS and Nodes using private subnet??

Comment: @JahadulRakib I'm not certain, it looks like is possible ( maybe this can help https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/arcsight/arcsight-platform-21.1/as_platform_admin_guide/Content/deployment_cloud/mount_targets_create.htm ) but in my tests it only worked in the public subnet.

Comment: already i make R&D. And also i successfully created and make operation using private subnet. But thanks for your response.